# Can we provide a User Name that needs to be run as by a pod/containers in kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-security, podsecuritypolicy

In `Pod` specification, there is an option to specify the user ID that needs to be run as by all containers

```
podSecurityContext:
  runAsUser: <a numeric Id>
```

Is there a way we can change the user name as well, the way we have for windows pods and container, like below

```
  securityContext:
    windowsOptions:
      runAsUserName: "ContainerUser"
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no such way. `WindowsSecurityContextOptions` contain **Windows-specific** options and credentials. [PodSecurityContext](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/workload-resources/pod-v1/#security-context) allows you to use:

> - `securityContext.runAsUser` (int64)
>
> The UID to run the entrypoint of the container process. Defaults to
> user specified in image metadata if unspecified. May also be set in
> SecurityContext. If set in both SecurityContext and
> PodSecurityContext, the value specified in SecurityContext takes
> precedence for that container.
>
> - `securityContext.runAsNonRoot` (boolean)
>
> Indicates that the container must run as a non-root user. If true, the
> Kubelet will validate the image at runtime to ensure that it does not
> run as UID 0 (root) and fail to start the container if it does. If
> unset or false, no such validation will be performed. May also be set
> in SecurityContext. If set in both SecurityContext and
> PodSecurityContext, the value specified in SecurityContext takes
> precedence.
>
> - `securityContext.runAsGroup` (int64)
>
> The GID to run the entrypoint of the container process. Uses runtime
> default if unset. May also be set in SecurityContext. If set in both
> SecurityContext and PodSecurityContext, the value specified in
> SecurityContext takes precedence for that container.

Trying to use String instead of Integer for `runAsUser` will result in error:

```
invalid type for io.k8s.api.core.v1.SecurityContext.runAsUser: got "string", expected "integer"
```